# How do I remove gaps between line segments of tikz's draw?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I have read the related question: [Tikz Understand white space between node and draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447513/tikz-understand-white-space-between-node-and-draw), and tried the solutions proposed therein.

I am trying to draw a phylogenetic tree. I define the leaves and internal node as tikz's `\node`, and connect them with `\draw`.

However, I can't seem to get rid of the gap between line segments in the drawn picture:

[image]

Here's what I'm writing to generate the above diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{internal}=[inner sep=0, outer sep=0, line cap=rect]
  \node (C) at (0, 0) {$C$};
  \node (H) at (1, 0) {$H$};
  \node[internal] (CH) at (0.5, 0.5) {};
  \draw (C) -- (CH) -- (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It includes the `inner sep=0`, `outer sep=0`, and `line cap=rect` options recommended in a similar question (linked above).

Comment: `\coordinate (CH) at (0.5, 0.5);`?

Comment: Use of `\tikzstyle` is discouraged. One should use `\tikzset{internal/.style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0, line cap=rect}}` instead. Though of course, a `coordinate` would be the proper solution in this case. And that could be done in the optional argument of `tikzpicture`: `\begin{tikzpicture}[internal/.style={...}]`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You're 100% right, I should have used `\coordinate`. My bad!

Comment: If you are drawing multiple trees, you should consider using one of the libraries or packages designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat) was right. I should be using coordinates instead of nodes for the internal nodes of the tree. This is my preferred solution over [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar)'s `++` syntax since I want to save the coordinate of the internal node for use later on.

Comment: ,@ning -- TikZ is powerful enough that you can still keep coordinates' names for later reference with a small modification on my code (see addendum). Relative coordinates are usually easier to use and modify, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2pt]
  \draw (0,0) node [below left]{$C$} -- ++(.5,.5) -- ++(.5,-.5) node[below right]{$H$};   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

It is easy to also keep coordinates' names for later reference using:

```
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label={below left:$C$}](C) -- ++(.5,.5)coordinate(CH) -- ++(.5,-.5) coordinate[label={below right:$H$}](H);
```